# matplotlib funcAnimation won't repeat

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I  am making a animated bar plot for basic bubble sort . It runs pretty good. But doesn't repeat itself (loop). I am trying it in jupyter notebook , I added **%matplotlib qt**,
Why won't my animFunc repeat although I have set the repeat to True .

```
x=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
y=[7,8,5,3,1,9,4,2,10,6]
temp=0
def animator_X():
    
    for a in range(len(y)-1):
        for b in range(len(y)-a-1):
            if y[b]>y[b+1]:
                temp = y[b]
                y[b]=y[b+1]
                y[b+1]=temp
                yield y

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,5))

def init():
        ax.clear()
        y=[7,8,5,3,1,9,4,2,10,6]
        plt.bar(x,y,color=['blue'])

def animX(i):
    ax.clear()
    plt.bar(x,y,color=['blue'])
    return plt
    



animx = FuncAnimation(fig,animX,frames=animator_X,interval=1000,init_func=init,repeat=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't resetting the main `y` variable when it repeats the `init` function after a run.
Try:

```py
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
x=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
y=[7,8,5,3,1,9,4,2,10,6]
temp=0
def animator_X():
    
    for a in range(len(y)-1):
        for b in range(len(y)-a-1):
            if y[b]>y[b+1]:
                temp = y[b]
                y[b]=y[b+1]
                y[b+1]=temp
                print(y)
                yield y

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,5))

def init():
    global y
    ax.clear()
    y=[7,8,5,3,1,9,4,2,10,6]
    plt.bar(x,y,color=['blue'])

def animX(i):
    ax.clear()
    plt.bar(x,y,color=['blue'])
    return plt
    
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animX,frames=animator_X,interval=100,init_func=init)
plt.show()
```

That code will run in sessions launched from [here](https://github.com/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder). Go [there](https://github.com/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder) and press `launch binder`. When it comes up, you can paste in the code.

I suspect in OP's code the addition of the `global y` line in the `init()` function will fix the OP's version.

**Further explanation**
It does keep repeating with the code posted in the OP because the kernel keeps running on that cell after the first pass.

A `y` object that is local solely to the `init` function is getting reset within the scope of the `init()` function when it repeats after the first pass. I don't know enough about how `FuncAnimation()` decides to update/and what it displays then to tell you why OP code without updating y in the main scope results in it showing the `init()` state and doesn't instead flash to the init state and then back to the sorted state. The kernel is still running and so maybe it is flashing between those two yet the `init()` dominates for some reason? That's speculation because the `FuncAnimation()` is so specialized that it doesn't display what is put in `print` statements inside the `init` or main function that gets animated, and so probing what's going on separate from the plot, in a simplistic manner, is not easy.

##### Update for JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+

Below is an update of the code example for use in JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+ (It requires installation of [`ipympl`](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/) prior):

```py
%matplotlib ipympl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
x=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
y=[7,8,5,3,1,9,4,2,10,6]
temp=0
def animator_X():
    
    for a in range(len(y)-1):
        for b in range(len(y)-a-1):
            if y[b]>y[b+1]:
                temp = y[b]
                y[b]=y[b+1]
                y[b+1]=temp
                print(y)
                yield y

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,5))

def init():
    global y
    ax.clear()
    y=[7,8,5,3,1,9,4,2,10,6]
    plt.bar(x,y,color=['blue'])

def animX(i):
    ax.clear()
    plt.bar(x,y,color=['blue'])
    return plt
    
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animX,frames=animator_X,interval=100,init_func=init)
anim;
```

Note that only the start and end have been adjusted from the original version I posted and actually only the change from `%matplotlib notebook` to `%matplotlib ipympl` is critical.

Because the original post was made back in 2022 & didn't mention JupyterLab, I assumed Jupyter Notebook was involved. And all that above will hold for Jupyter Notebook 6.4 and earlier (and should be hold for NbClassic at present; if it's not clear why I am bringing up version numbers or what those terms are, see the second half of [my answer here that references resources detailing how the Jupyter ecosystem changed a lot in 2023 with Jupyter Notebook 7+ being built on the same components as JupyterLab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004)). And because of that I've updated the end of this post going to update the top of this to provide better guidance of how to use it with JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+ now.
You can try it in JupyterLab with an session served by MyBinder where `ipympl` has already beein installed and so everything is set for the code above to work by going here and clicking the '`launch binder`' badge under 'Direct links to start out in notebook mode in JupyterLab full-featured mode:' (or [click here directly to launch](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/master?urlpath=%2Flab%2Ftree%2Fnotebooks%2FDonut%20plot%20on%20a%20widget%20tab.ipynb)). (I don't right now have a good environment for using Jupyter Notebook 7+ to offer. It is possible though even if `ipympl` is not previously installed in the session, see [the middle of my post here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/matplotlib-animation-not-appearing-in-jupyter-notebook/24938/5?u=fomightez) for the steps to get such a session working.)