# New Jupyter Notebook Interface

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I cannot figure out why my jupyter notebook looks different. I did my usual setup, where I created a virtual environment with python 3.9 so `python -m venv my_env` and the installed jupyter notebook `pip install jupyter notebook`. The jupyter notebook looks completely different. Can anyone help me on how to get back to the original one?

What I want to get back to:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S37En.png)

What I currently have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gP8e.png)

I tried reinstalling jupyter notebook. The current version is 7.0.2

Comment: You answered your own first sentence ("I cannot figure out why my jupyter notebook looks different.") with your last sentence ("The current version is 7.0.2.") Projects develop and you may find it advantageous to keep up with the changes. (Or at least be aware of the the developments.) Sometimes there's options to keep the more familiar. In your case, you are looking for **NbClassic**. The developers have made that the way to keep the older style interface. I'll post an answer so that I can point to more resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "The jupyter notebook looks completely different. Can anyone help me on how to get back to the original one?"

To address the second question quoted, you are looking for **NbClassic**.   The developers have made that the way to keep the older style interface.

From the [NbClassic repository](https://github.com/jupyter/nbclassic):

> "NbClassic provides a backwards compatible Jupyter Notebook interface that you can install side-by-side with the latest versions: That way, you can fearlessly upgrade without worrying about your classic extensions and customizations breaking.
> How does it work?
> Because NbClassic provides the classic interface on top of the new Jupyter Server backend, it can coexist with other frontends like JupyterLab and Notebook 7 in the same installation. NbClassic preserves the custom classic notebook experience under a new set of URL endpoints, under the namespace /nbclassic/."

More about that and the answers to your first questions are covered by looking into the following resources that discusses recent developments in regards to the interface options for editing and running `.ipynb` files in the Jupyter ecosystem.

- [Jupyter Notebook 6.5.0 Release Candidate](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyter-notebook-6-5-0-release-candidate-4c229c6dab55) has two sections right near the start 'Notebook 6 vs Notebook 7' and 'NbClassic' that you'll want to examine.
- [Announcing Jupyter Notebook 7](https://blog.jupyter.org/announcing-jupyter-notebook-7-8d6d66126dcf)
- As to why you may want to consider changing to JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook 7 and beyond, see [JupyterLab 4.0 is Here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-4-0-is-here-388d05e03442) to get a sense of the new landscape and what building Jupyter Notebook 7 and beyond on JupyterLab components means is possible.

More on Jupyter ecosystem, an overview:
https://twitter.com/jtpio/status/1683399787876429825    July 2023

> "Our talk with @JohanMabille on Navigating the Jupyter Landscape is now available on YouTube  
> Check it out if you want a high-level overview of the Jupyter ecosystem and learn more about the underlying projects and libraries.[Jeremy Tuloup, Johan Mabille Navigating the Jupyter Landscape | JupyterCon 2023](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWJ0-OPKTxI)"

Answer (score 0):

for the NbClassic, you need to downgrade to notebook version 6.1.*

Comment: Version 6.1 isn't **NbClassic**. It is 'Classic Notebook v6'. (Specifically, "NbClassic provides the classic interface on top of the new Jupyter Server backend", see [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbclassic#how-does-it-work)). See [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook#maintained-versions) for more about 'Classic Notebook v6'. And why not recommend 6.4 based on [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook#classic-notebook-v6)?