# Jupyter interface looks different

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

[My Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtKkM.png)

Does anyone know how to change this view to the one with cells? On my laptop, which is using Windows 11, seemed to have the normal jupyter notebook interface with all the cells showing. However, on my windows 10 pc, the jupyter notebook only has lines of code as shown in the image.

I tried to change some of the settings, but nothing seemed to work. Even tried updating Jupyter.

Comment: Please [do not post images of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Your post is basically a duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76836781/8508004) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-notebook-menu-missing-options/20868?u=fomightez). (And now [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76926554/8508004) that I happened to see just before yours.) The interface of Jupyter Notebook Version7 is different. See my coverage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004). If you prefer to continue with the older interface understanding that there will be a more limited forward development path, you should look into NbClassic.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are opening a file with `.py` file extension on your Jupiter notebook. for a file to open up with the cells view, you'll have to open a notebook which has a `.ipynb` file extension. Or create a new notebook.