# I can't display titles in Markdown in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

There is a problem in displaying the markdowns as titles in the jupyter notebook on localhost. Also the version is strange but it appears to be 7.0.4 anyways, so could you please help me solve this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: About "Also the version is strange but it appears to be 7.0.4", I am assuming you may be saying 'strange' because the interface has some differences? See [Announcing Jupyter Notebook 7](https://blog.jupyter.org/announcing-jupyter-notebook-7-8d6d66126dcf), especially under the section 'A Familiar Document-Oriented Experience'. See the second half of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) for more info and resources. The top of that answer covers an option if you prefer the pre-7 look and possibilities. But 7+ and JupyterLab are the main path forward for the project.

Comment: About your issue...your post is light on details. Not following what you see. And you don't supply much more information on your system besides the version of Jupyter Notebook. And hence I cannot tell if you might be encountering [this issue reported issue for Windows users entitled 'JN7 markdown cells mess'](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/7002)? Or if it is something else. There are [several open issues reported for markdown](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+markdown). Including specific markdown code you are using & how it looks would be best.

Comment: This is about a mac OS version - there is a problem in displaying the title in markdown cells - the problem being that the hashtags are displayed anyways even with a space and that I can't seem to have a correct display of heading either

Comment: That eliminates it being linked to that Windows issue. Have you tried other browsers on your local machine by any chance? I notice you mention space. Are you including a space between your text and pound signs?  For example if I start Jupyter Notebook 7.0.4 from [here](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/35a72862c8be13dee31b61ebac2d9786) by clicking 'launch binder' & starting a new notebook, I see that `# Test` and `## Test` work in a markdown cell but that `#Test` or `##Test` don't.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant, but both won't work in the notebook. I don't have a title option as well on the drop menu for code or markdown - it is replaced by a dash. I don't know how to change browser in the config, but I actually do think this is not the right problem

Comment: It just started working out of the blue with no apparent reason - I just updated notebook with pip install ... but the layout of the dash has not changed. So I don't really know what happened

Comment: That inconsistent behavior indicates a probable incomplete installation. I'm glad that the markdown rendering seemed to suddenly start working. (Maybe that was after the `pip install`?) I would suggest trying to install the Anaconda Distribution and using the Anaconda Navigator to launch and use Jupyter products.

Comment: I understand. I don't like anaconda display so I use it directly on the terminal. But thanks for the help

Comment: I understand but it may be cleaner about installing than the process you followed.