# How do Jupyter Notebook extensions add functionality to a notebook?

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Given that behind the scenes the data in a Jupyter notebook is JSON, I assume that a similar simple system is used for notebook extensions.

However, I haven't been able to figure out exactly how they work from the [`nb_extensions`](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) documentation.

How do they add functionality to Jupyter, and can this be mimicked by making additions to the Jupyter JSON file?

Comment: "However, I haven't been able to figure out exactly how they work from the nb_extensions documentation."  -- So you know, that system you reference is an "end-of-life" path. That way will only work with NbClassic going forward, and development there is only for maintenance as of now. If none of that sounds familiar, see [the second half of my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) about the recent changes in the Jupyter ecosystem. You want the current extensions system if you want something that works for current Jupyter products.

Comment: <continued> If you want current information about developing extensions that work in Jupyter's current focus, go [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html#extensions) and [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_dev.html#developer-extensions) and [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring/plugins.html#managing-plugins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by looking at the [github repo](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions), it seems that the extensions are not made from JSON, but instead from html,css,javascript etc. also, according to the [internal](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/internals.html) docs, the best way to add new features to jupyter is to clone their repo, create a new directory (under the `src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions` directory), add a .yaml for configuration, a README file, and a javascript file for the extention's code.

btw, it seems that `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` is dependent on another package called [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator). so you might want to look into this

Comment: Thank you for the reference! Do you think there's a way of replicating the behaviour using JSON?

Comment: well, i know it's possibile to turn JSON into yaml and xml, and i also remember hearing about a compiler for compiling JSON into javascript (i couldn't find it though). if you used all of those togather, then i guess it would be _possible_ to create an extension using only JSON.        edit: i looked it up using chatgpt and it seems that javascript can parse json files into an interface, so if you want, you can make some code for parsing that interface into javascript code, so you will still have to write some code for the compilation, but after that, you could use only json for the extension.