# why does jupyterthemes command return error?

Tags: python, themes, jupyter

I would like to have a dark theme in Jupyter notebook.

I did a pip install of jupyterthemes but when I input "jt -1" it doesn't work. "jt -h" or any of the other commands don't work either.

my version of python is 3.11

```
pip install jupyterthemes
jt -1
```

Comment: I assume you are referencing [https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes)? You don't say which version of Jupyter you are now using. As discussed [here](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes#scaling-back-support) in the context of JupyterLab, this doesn't work there and so since there is a better solution with JupyterLab there isn't really support for the project. And now that Jupyter Notebook 7+ is out, that software won't work because Jupyter Notebook 7+ is build on JupyterLab tech. There was recently a big shakeup in the Jupyter ecosystem ...

Comment: <continued> , see [the second half of my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) if you are unaware. The only version information you provide is Python and you aren't clear if that is your system or what Jupyter has. Additionally you don't even give the result of what happens when you run `jt -1`, and so without a lot more details **in your post** giving you these suggestions are the limit.