# widget from ipywidgets.interact() is not displayed in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm trying to make use of some `ipywidgets` utilities to make my jupyter notebook interactive.
I'm supposed to get a widget but instead I can only see a string perpesentation of a widget object:
[widgets_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI2uP.png)

I have the last stable version of `ipywidgets` and all its dependencies installed in a separate conda environment which I'm using:
[versions_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avJBh.png)

I tried to get all the packages reinstalled with a new environment but it did not help.

I also tried using `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension` and `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix` as it is [suggested](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html#installing-into-classic-jupyter-notebook-5-2-or-earlier) in the installation guide for some older versions of jupyter but it did not work causing a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widgetsnbextension'`

Comment: Seeing a string representation of a widget object often means while you have successfully imported ipywidgets, it isn't installed completely right in the particular environment or perhaps Jupyter version you are using at the current time.  The stuff you list in the last paragraph has nothing to do with JupyterLab and should not be being used here. On another note of something you share you may have better experience when running in a notebook using `%conda` and not `!conda`. The magic version will run in the environment where it is running and the version with exclamation won't necessarily.

Comment: <continued> Your 'version screen' only refers to JupyterLab and so you should have the title of this post be 'widget from ipywidgets.interact() is not displayed in JupyterLab' and correct the category tags correspondingly, too. The last paragraph would only be pertinent to Jupyter Notebook version 6.4 or earlier, or if you are using NbClassic. If some of those terms mean nothing to you, you should see [the second half of my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) as the Jupyter landscape right now is rather complex.

Comment: Does this have to work locally for you or could you work and develop and share on a remote session where ipywidgets is already working properly? I can refer you to a MyBinder.org-served session where that is the case or you can use [JupyterLite](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_static/lab/index.html?path=intro.ipynb) (there should be a notebook `interactive-widgets.ipynb` in the 'pyodide' folder there that you can step through running).