# Nbextensions Tab for Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I'm trying to install Nbextensions to get the table of contents for my Jupyter notebook. I was on version 7.something for jupyter notebook and the Nb configurations tab would not show up.

I looked through the github forum and they said to downgrade to version 6.1.5, which I did. Now, the tab shows up but my configurations is pretty much blank, and says that "edit menu item" is only configurable for version 4x or 5x. So I downgrade again to 5x for my jupyter notebook, and now the compatability is marked green but I still do not get the full interface. Please help!

For reference, I am using pip3.

Comment: The old Nbextensions stuff is not for Jupyter Notebook 7+ so no need for a  Nb configurations tab. You can use NbClassic if you need to still use those and not the current extensions meant for JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+ which now share most of the same underlying tech. You may want to check out the bottom of [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) if some of this is not making sense.  However, you should be good with default Jupyter Notebook 7+ if all you need is  a Table of Contents accessible.  ...

Comment: <continued> **BOTH JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+ include a Table of Contents by default.**   See [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebook_7_features.html#id1) for more about it in Jupyter Notebook 7+ . (And `pip3` is probably no longer needed if you happen to start with newer stuff eventually as you'd not have need for Python 2.7 and so it'd just be `pip`. May be best just to wait until you have a new computer though if you are worried about messing things up too much on your current system.)

Comment: By the way as for your downgrading stuff....If you had the newer undering tech on there with `jupyter-sever` and then tried downgrading it may have stuff still interfering. You may have to clean much better to get that to work. I'd suggest though moving to NbClassic for using the extensions. The suggestions to downgrade may have been old and not well-informed?