# Getting 'Jupyter command `jupyter-nbextension` not found.' error when trying to install an extension

Tags: jupyter-notebook, command-line

Trying to run this command: `jupyter nbextension install --py webcatjupyterplugin` following the instructions here: https://github.com/CSSPLICE/webcatjupyterplugin

Full error message:

```
usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir] [--paths] [--json] [--debug] [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands: console contrib dejavu events execute kernel kernelspec lab labextension labhub migrate
nbconvert nbextensions_configurator notebook qtconsole run server troubleshoot trust

Jupyter command `jupyter-nbextension` not found.
```

However no matter what I try, nbextensions can never be found. Tried downgrading jupyter and deleting and reinstalling. Quite lost on what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In a post like this you need to supply versions of the software you are trying to presently use. Jupyter Notebook 7+ aren't compatible with nbextensions. JupyterLab also ins't. You'd need Jupyter Notebook 6.4 or lower or NbClassic. If those terms mean little to you, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) about recent changes in the Jupyter ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```