# nbextensions not showing in jupyter notebook: Command `jupyter-contrib` not found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I'm trying to install nbextensions in jupyter notebook so I can hide code from slideshow.

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

Error.

```
Jupyter command `jupyter-contrib` not found.
```

Any ideas

Comment: What version of Jupyter Notebook? Nbextensions don't work in the current Jupyter Notebook 7+. See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77842943/8508004) for a similar recent question.

Comment: @Wayne thank you. I'm easing my way into notebooks after using VSCode and not to speed.