# Jupyter Notebook interface issue and missing in Anaconda Navigator after creating a new environment on Mac M1

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, apple-m1

I'm encountering an issue with Jupyter Notebook on my Mac M1 after creating a new environment using Anaconda Navigator. When I launch Jupyter Notebook from the new environment, the interface appears outdated, and Jupyter Notebook doesn't show up on the Anaconda Navigator homepage for the new environment.

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Created a new environment using Conda.
2. Installed Jupyter packages in the new environment.
3. Activated the environment and launched Jupyter Notebook.

Despite these steps, the interface is outdated, and Jupyter Notebook is missing from the Anaconda Navigator homepage.

Things I've tried:

- Updated Jupyter Notebook in the new environment using `conda install -n myenv jupyter notebook --upgrade`.
- Checked and confirmed the Python version in the new environment.
- Verified the correct environment is being used in the Jupyter Notebook interface.

I'm seeking advice on how to resolve this issue, update the Jupyter interface in the new environment, and ensure its proper integration with Anaconda Navigator on Mac M1.

Comment: I'm unclear on some things. Was launching Jupyter Notebook from the Anaconda Navigator working before these recent issues? You say the interface looks 'outdated'? That is really subjective. Any chance you have installed Jupyter Notebook 7+ and just aren't used to it? If you aren't aware what that could mean, see the seconda half of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004). Otherwise that is very confusing because the only options really are three interfaces at this time for Jupyter: JupyterLab, Jupyter Notebook 6.4 or 6.5/NbClassic, or Jupyter Notebook 7+.

Comment: As to your issue, I will say I've seen that some people reported needing to specify the exact version of Jupyter to update in the commands to get it to work. And I think it was on Macs that occurred, if I recall correctly. I'll try to dig up some links for that later. However, I'm not going to invest time time to do that yet given the confusion about what 'outdated' could mean.

Comment: Having checked it, it is indeed Jupyter Notebook 7. I'm aware the looks are subjective, but it looks very different to the previous version (6.5.4) in ways that made me assume it was some old version of it. However, the issue of Jupyter notebook not showing up in the home menu still persists with freshly-created environments, although copying the "lib" folder from the main "anaconda3" folder and pasting it in the environment folder solves the issue, but it's rather inconvenient to do it by hand.

Comment: Yes, that copying the 'lib' library sounds like a pain. I don't know if the Anaconda folks can do anything to rectify this. Overall though you seem to be making some progress. Did you have Anaconda before on there? Or did you start with the newest version only? If you are starting with the newest version only it may pay to not get too invested in using it as-is, meaning keep your environments portable so you can copy them and update Anaconda soon when they release a new version, which hopefully may have a fix for this on your system.