# How do I access this ribbon in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

[jupyter notebook ribbon image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vpik.png)

(novice here)

I just installed anaconda on a windows 10 machine and opened jupyter notebook on Microsoft Edge. I saw this ribbon that I have never seen before.

It is a on a fresh windows and I haven't installed any extensions or anything else on edge. I have used jupyter notebook before and I normally use Firefox for it but I have never seen this ribbon before.

Does anyone know how to access it or find it?

Google search but didnt find a result. I want to know if there is a way to access it.

Comment: I added an image but it doesn't seem to show here. I have tried again and it has let me add a link instead of an image.

Comment: That looks correct for Jupyter Notebook 7+. What versions of Jupyter are you discussing? To see what Jupyter Notebook 7.1 looks like, go [here](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/83b0b625cb3b6e05d7f3d8714f98182e) and click 'launch binder'. Notebook 7+ changes things a bit from Notebook 6 and earlier, see [the second half of my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) for context.

Comment: And if you want the old style, you'd need to install NbClassic, which is discussed in the first part of [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004). As a novice, I wouldn't recommend that because you'll further fall out of sync with what other Jupyter users are using and advice won't match.

Comment: Yes you are correct, its 7+. Now I need to update the old one which will require reinstall. Thank you.