# Jupyter command `jupyter-bundlerextension` not found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I use jupyter notebook version 7.0.8. I was able to install the jupyter_to_medium package but still didn't see the deploy to Medium post on the notebook. So I tried this line of code to display it: `jupyter bundlerextension enable --py jupyter_to_medium._bundler --sys-prefix` , then got the error message below

```
usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir] [--paths] [--json] [--debug] [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

options:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands: console dejavu events execute kernel kernelspec lab labextension labhub migrate nbconvert
notebook qtconsole run script server troubleshoot trust

Jupyter command `jupyter-bundlerextension` not found.
```

Comment: kindly run this command and show the result .  pip show jupyter_to_medium .

Comment: (I'm somewhat worried this hasn't been updated to work with Jupyter Notebook 7+. If you look at [the repo](https://github.com/dexplo/jupyter_to_medium), you'll see it hasn't been updated about a year ago.) If it has been updated and works, you should just be able to install with `pip` as covered [here](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-to-medium/). `jupyter bundlerextension enable` won't work with Jupyter Notebook 7+ **and so that is why you see that error**. There only lists it working with Python 3.10 and you may have newer version?

Comment: <continued> Extensions are installed and activated differently in Jupyter Notebook 7+, in the same way they are installed and activated in JupyterLab 3+ because Jupyter Notebook 7+ uses JupyterLab components. See [the second half of my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) for resources to learn more about the new ecosystem. You could possibly use NbClassic and continue to install (`%pip install ` run in the notebook with NbClassic) and activate it with that command perhaps. I'd at least have more hope it would fully work there given it hasn't been updated in a year.

Comment: @tousifNoor, This is the result of pip show jupyter_to_medium: Name: jupyter-to-medium
Version: 0.2.4
Summary: Publish a Jupyter Notebook as a Medium blogpost
Home-page: https://github.com/dexplo/jupyter_to_medium
Author: Ted Petrou
Author-email: petrou.theodore@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
Requires: beautifulsoup4, matplotlib, nbconvert, numpy, requests
Required-by:

Comment: @Wayne, thanks for your response. I will try the tips and update you with the outcome.

Comment: @Wayne, so I installed nbclassic and was able to open the notebook in nbclassic. Fortunately the deploy tab is on that notebook. But when I clicked on Deply-> Medium Post, I got the error response 404:Not Found. You are requesting a page that does not exist!

Comment: That seems like significant progress at least. Maybe look around the issues for the package for problems when pressing 'Deploy'?